# Full Calender Customize For Week

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have referred to this URL (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resourceColumns-demo), and i require left side list to be mapped with each day , no time require in this. Each Person would be mapped weekly or each day on left. I want to get event date with Person Id on Event Click.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R01Be.png)
 below is image as done:

Comment: To do as you suggest would require a completely [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js). But it is **not** a simple task to create one. Please consider first whether you can use one of the existing views successfully, to get an effect similar enough to your desired result. For instance, the [Resource Timeline](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view) view is essentially the same as what you are describing, but just rotated by 90 degrees. I'm sure it would be just fine really. It can be configured to show just whole days as the duration, instead of times of day.

Comment: Like I said, you need to change the _duration_. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration is what you need. You might also find https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelInterval and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat useful